# Hyperlink in subgrid Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I want to add Hyperlink for each row in subgrid. What I am looking is I want to display a invoice number as a link. When user clicks on that it should open a external window. Already tried with Hyperlink field available Dynamics. But its comes with https://.. I don't want to show the URL inside the grid.

Already tried with Hyperlink field available Dynamics. But its comes with https://.. I don't want to show the URL inside the grid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to implement this requirement but there are ways:

1. Create own PCF data-set type control that renders the data the way you want it to see but it would be a lot of work to implement the small requirement.
2. Use Powerapps Grid control and custom renderer for the column. You can find more information here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/customize-editable-grid-control